# Is it possible to combine java and groovy sources in the gradle project?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I have the following project structure:

```
src
|
|--main
    |
    |--java
    |    |
    |    |--p
    |       |--S.java
    |  
    |
    |--groovy
         |
         |--p
            |--Main.groovy
```

the thing I want learn is how to combine java and groovy compiled classes together. Imagine that `S.java` contains the following:

```
package p;

public class S {
    public static void p() {
        System.out.println("p");
    }
}
```

and Main.groovy:

```
package p

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        S.p
    }
}
```

Now, the build script I've written is the simplest and contains merely

```
apply plugin : 'groovy'
```

What I want to achieve by the command `build gradle` is to get a `jar` file to using with JVM. But instead I got the following error:

```
Cannot infer Groovy class path because no Groovy Jar was found on class path: co
nfiguration ':compile'
```

Could you possibly help me to fix that error?

Comment: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html#N12C41

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Applying `groovy` plugin gives You tasks for groovy compilation and docs etc., but *does not* provide dependency for groovy itself so what You're missing is:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.3.7'
}
```

Comment: Sure, I just forgot to do it)

Comment: If u get 'unable to resolve class GroovyTestCase' simply use the 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.7' dependency